# Передача non-ascii значения в заголовке

Tags: кодировка, proxy, httpclient, .net-core-3.0-webapi

Пишу прокси. От сервера приходит ответ, пытаюсь скопировать все заголовки в ответ клиенту и получаю ошибку:

> ```
>   Message "Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header: 0x00C7"  string
> ```

Как ретранслировать такое значение заголовка в сторону клиента?

рабочий код для копирования заголовков:

```
  private void CopyResponseHeaders(HttpResponseMessage original, HttpResponse copy)
    {
        foreach (var header in original.Headers)
            copy.Headers[header.Key] = header.Value.ToArray();

        foreach (var header in original.Content.Headers)

                copy.Headers[header.Key] = new StringValues(header.Value.ToArray());
    }
```

Опрашиваемых серверов достаточно много, в связи с чем, написание решений под каждый является весьма затруднительным.
Возможно, есть какие-нибудь универсальные решения?

Comment: Так возьмите стандартный urlencode

Comment: В таком случае браузер не может корректно декодировать имя файла, ведь оно будет закодировано 2 раза.
В итоге, браузер получая файл, декодирует его из urlencode в ту кодировку, в которой он закодирован изначально.

Comment: О, ещё и какое-то имя файла всплыло. А с чего это оно будет закодировано два раза?

Comment: Я получаю от сервера ответ в виде HttpResponseMessage, значения из которого нужно передать в сторону клиента. 
Но, при попытке скопировать все заголовки, в частности Content-disposition, получаю ошибку  non-ASCII.  Так как не известно в какой кодировке находится заголовок, полученный с конкретного сервера, то и корректно декодировать-кодировать не могу. При попытке дополнительно кодировать заголовок в Urlencode, на клиенте он декодируется в тот формат, в котором он был получен изначально.